# Must the fine structure constant be an irrational number?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants

This question concerns a conjecture on the nature of $\alpha = e^2/4\pi\epsilon\hbar c$ in light of black hole holes. Let me consider the Reissnor-Nordstrom metric for a charged black hole
$$
ds^2 = \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r} + \frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)dt^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r} + \frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2 - r^2d\Omega^2.
$$
The coefficient for the charge is 
$$
Q^2 = \frac{q^2G}{4\pi\epsilon c^4} =  \left(\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon\hbar c}\right)\frac{G\hbar}{c^3} = n^2\alpha L_p^2,
$$
where the charge of the black hole hole is $q = ne$, or n units of electric charge so that this coefficient is an integer times the fine structure constant times a Planck unit of area. The condition for the vanishing of the metric coefficient  $1 - 2m/r + Q^2/r^2 = 0$ is $r_\pm = m\pm\sqrt{m^2 - Q^2}$. This can be expressed entirely according to Planck units for the mass as N units of the Planck mass with $m = GM/c^2$ $= NGM_p/c^2 = N\ell_p$.  The mass is then in units of Planck lengths, and the horizons are expressed as
$$
r_\pm = (N \pm \sqrt{N^2 - n^2\alpha})\ell_p
$$
Let us take the product $r_+r_-$
$$
r_+r_- = n^2\alpha\ell_p^2
$$
The extremal condition is where $N^2 =  n^2\alpha$ and $r_+ = r_- = m$ $= N\ell_p$.

This leads to the interesting conjecture. The extremal condition is $\alpha = (N/n)^2$. This leads to the following interesting hypothesis: The fine structure constant must be an irrational number. If we admit the chronology or cosmic censorship conditions then the spacelike condition of a naked singularity is avoided. If the fine structure constant is an irrational number the null condition is avoided, and the extremal black hole is not possible.

This leads to a further question. If the fine structure constant is irrational there is not enough quantum information in the black hole or the universe to measure and record it. Does this mean that a black hole can becomes sufficiently close to extremality that the uncertainty in $\alpha$ out to some huge decimal point defines some sort of minimum temperature similar to a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Comment: There is *no* reason at all, within the currently accepted theories, to believe that mass has to come in integer units of Planck mass or Planck length. That is, you know nothing about $N$, and hence nothing about the (ir)rationality of $\alpha$. It's therefore not clear what the argument or question here is supposed to be.

Comment: Another problem is 'rational vs. irrational' has no place in physics, by continuity. No physical (measurable) number "exists" out to further than 100 decimal places, so you can consider everything to be rational.

Comment: There is a lot of literature about black holes in Planck mass units and qubits on horizons as Planck units of area.

Comment: are you also suggesting that a black hole can measure the algorithmic information of a physical constant, or somehow incorporate that number on its entropy?

Comment: Is $N$ an integer or a positive rational number?

Comment: To see how ridiculous the idea of integer $N$ is, consider that the Planck mass is around 22µg. Are you seriously trying to tell us there is nothing lighter than 22 µg?

Comment: Of course I am using the idea of a black hole as having algorithmic content. If an extremal black hole exists then for $N$ Planck areas of qubits on the horizon due to mass, and $n$ charges which also adjust the area of the horizon an extremal BH would compute $\alpha = (N/n)^2. Given that $N$ and $n$ are integers it would compute a rational number. My question or hypothesis is that this does not happen.

Comment: Both $N$ and $n$ are integers. For an extremal black hole the fine structure constant would be a rational number. Of course it is an empirical number, and we can't ever prove it is rational or irrational, but if extremal condition is not physically possible it would seem to suggest that the fine structure constant has no exact number. In fact with the limits on the quantity of information physically available it would suggest that ultimately it has no exact value. At some point after $10^{10}$, a number used as an example, decimal points it is unknowable.

Comment: "If the fine structure constant is irrational there is not enough quantum information in the black hole or the universe to measure and record it."  The sqrt(2) is irrational; one can record it with two sides of the unit square, or with a repeating continued fraction.  Nature is not a computer limited by the number of digits required for a computation, so this assertion makes no sense to me.

Comment: These are representations of $\sqrt{2}$, but they are not the number itself.

Answer (score 3):

The idea that distances have to be integer multiples of the Planck length is a common misunderstanding. The actual role of the Planck length is a bit subtler than that. In quantum mechanics, the possible observable values of a physical quantity (such as a particle's position) are the eigenvalues of a Hermitian operator associated with that quantity. But the eigenvalues of the operators corresponding to spatial coordinates are not discretised in units of the Planck length.

The unit's significance comes in a positive lower bound on the $\Delta x$ of a particle in the uncertainty principle. (This uncertainty is a standard deviation in the position's probability distribution, not a gap between adjacent values in the spectrum.) To measure the particle's position to an accuracy of at most $\Delta x$ requires a photon of momentum $\geq\tfrac{\hbar}{2\Delta x}$. Its mass is $\geq\tfrac{\hbar}{2c\Delta x}$, and its Schwarzschild radius is $\geq\tfrac{G\hbar}{c^3\Delta x}=\tfrac{\ell_P^2}{\Delta x}$. To prevent the particle being captured within this radius, we need $\Delta x\geq\tfrac{\ell_P^2}{\Delta x}$, so $\Delta x\geq\ell_P$.

Comment: I can't make the question too long. The Planck area is the minimal area one can isolate a qubit. The Planck length is as you say a lower bound on a particle uncertainty, which means one can't find a qubit in a region smaller than a Planck area. This is in line with what you are writing. Black hole horizons as integral numbers of Planck areas is a fairly common concept. I am a bit surprised by the umbrage this seems to have provoked.